# BibTeX -- how to write more information in the output

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I have a nice detailed bib file, but the output shows more less, than I want.

```
@book{konstruktionselemente,
  title={{Konstruktionselemente des Maschinenbaus~2: Grundlagen von Maschinenelementen f{\"u}r Antriebsaufgaben}},
  author={\textsc{Steinhilper}, Waldemar and \textsc{Sauer}, Bernd},
  series={6. Auflage},
  publisher={Springer-Lehrbuch}
  year={2008},
  isbn={978-3-540-76653-7},
  url={http://www.springer.com/engineering/mechanical+eng/book/978-3-540-76653-7},
  pages={30-45}}
```

What should I do, to write out all informations from the bib file? How can I controll what should be visible?

Comment: This is down to your bibliography style - which one do you use?

Comment: Your bib-file is corrupt -- the comma after the publisher field is missing which means that everything afterwards will be gobbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's  how to do it using [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) and its `\footfullcite` macro. I added the missing comma in your `.bib` file and also removed some formatting macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

% last name of authors in small caps
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@book{konstruktionselemente,
  title={Konstruktionselemente des Maschinenbaus~2: Grundlagen von Maschinenelementen für Antriebsaufgaben},
  author={Steinhilper, Waldemar and Sauer, Bernd},
  edition={6},
  publisher={Springer-Lehrbuch},
  year={2008},
  isbn={978-3-540-76653-7},
  url={http://www.springer.com/engineering/mechanical+eng/book/978-3-540-76653-7},
  pages={30-45},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footfullcite{konstruktionselemente}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: While I still recommend biblatex, simply adding the missing comma in your `.bib` file may be the right answer for you.

Comment: now I implemented theese informations in my document with defaults and it works pretty good. It prints so much, as I want. I like it ;)
Thanks!